# Not able to Insert data into Hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I created hive table using following query:

```
create table students (name varchar(64), age int, gpa decimal(3, 2));
```

and inserted the data using this query:

```
insert into table students values ('fred flinstone', 445, 1.34);
```

It doesn't show any error but when i am viewing the data using

```
select * from students
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I get this same error when i am joining table in Hive.

Comment: Hi, on hive-1.1.0-cdh5.14.2 it's working well.

Comment: Are you query the table from Hue - Hive? If it's from hue, verify twice that you are on Hive and not on Impala.

Comment: Its working fine. please share the additional  details